# normal cone to sublevel set

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I came across the following interesting and important result:

Let $f$ be a proper convex function and $\bar{x}$ be an interior point of ${\rm dom} f$. Denote the sublevel set $\{x:f(x)\leq f(\bar{x})\}$  by $C$ and the normal cone to $C$ at $\bar{x}$ by $N_C(\bar{x})$. Moreover, assume that $f(\bar{x})>\inf f(x)$. Then, we have $N_C(\bar{x})={\rm cone}\, \partial f(\bar{x})$.

Many textbooks have this result as a theorem. But most of them proved this result by citing many other results. The basic idea is to show $(T_C(\bar{x}))^{\circ}={\rm cone}\,\partial f(\bar{x})$, where $T_C(\bar{x})$ is the tangent cone to $C$ at $\bar{x}$.

I tried to show this result by a naive approach, i.e., by showing $N_C(\bar{x})\supset{\rm cone}\,\partial f(\bar{x})$ and $N_C(\bar{x})\subset{\rm cone}\,\partial f(\bar{x})$. Indeed, it is trivial to show $N_C(\bar{x})\supset{\rm cone}\,\partial f(\bar{x})$. The difficulty comes from the other direction.

I am wondering if there is any simple/insightful way to show this result.

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you come across this?

Comment: This is indeed an exercise in Borwein's book: Convex analysis and nonlinear optimization. Although it is an exercise, I think it is very useful to relate many stuff together. As I mentioned, it appears in many other textbooks as a theorem in a bit different form.

Answer (score 2):

Proof of $R_+ \partial f(\bar{x})\supset  N _C(\bar{x})$ (by contradiction)  :

(1). $\bar{x} \in core(dom f)$ $\Rightarrow$ $\partial f(\bar{x})$ is bounded.

(2). $f(\bar{x}) > \inf f$ $\Rightarrow$  $0 \notin \partial f(\bar{x})$.

Assume that  $R_+ \partial f(\bar{x})   \supset  N _C(\bar(x))$ doesn't hold. Then there exists nonzero $d$ such that $d \in N _C(\bar{x})$ and $d \not\in R_+ \partial f(\bar{x})$. Let $D=R_+\{d\} $. Then $\partial f(\bar{x}) \bigcap D=\emptyset$.

From (1), (2) and hyperplane separation theorem, there exists
$a$ such that $\langle a, d \rangle \geq 0$ and $\langle a, \phi\rangle < -\epsilon$ for any $\phi \in \partial f(\bar{x}) $, where $\epsilon>0$.

From the max formula, $f'(\bar{x},a)<0$. Thus, $a$ is a descent direction for $f$, we have $\langle a, d\rangle <0$, which leads to a contradiction.

Comment: Can you state explicitly the particular hyperplane separation theorem you’re using here? (A reference would be great too if you have one.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possibility to show the reverse direction
and the only used fact is
\begin{equation*}
 f'(\bar x; d ) = \sup_{\lambda \in \partial f(\bar x)} \langle \lambda, d \rangle
 .
\end{equation*}
The desired inclusion $N_C(\bar x) \subset \mathrm{cone}\partial f(\bar x)$
is equivalent to
$N_C(\bar x)^\circ \supset \mathrm{cone}\partial f(\bar x)^\circ$,
that is, we have to show
\begin{equation*}
 T_C(\bar x) \supset \partial f(x)^\circ,
\end{equation*}
since $\partial f(\bar x)^\circ \supset \mathrm{cone}\partial f(\bar x)^\circ$.
Let $d \in \partial f(\bar x)^\circ$ be given.
Hence, for all $\lambda \in \partial f(\bar x)$, we have
\begin{equation*}
 \langle \lambda, d \rangle \le 0
\end{equation*}
and this means
\begin{equation*}
 f'(\bar x;d) \le 0.
\end{equation*}
By using a point $\tilde x$ with $f(\tilde x) < f(\bar x)$, it is easy to show
\begin{equation*}
 f\Big( (1-\lambda_n) \, (\bar x + n^{-1} \, d) + \lambda_n \, \tilde x \Big)
 \le
 f(\bar x),
\end{equation*}
with $\lambda_n = \mathcal{o}(1/n)$,
which yields $d \in T_C(\bar x)$.

This proof is also insightful.
It just means that if you have a direction $d$,
which is polar to all subgradients, it has to be a descent direction (i.e. $f'(\bar x;d) \le 0$)
and thus lies in the tangent cone of $C$.

Comment: Hi, gerw: could you please provide more detail about the last inequality? By the way, I think you also make use of the fact that ${\rm cone}\,\partial f(\bar{x})$ is closed. Thus, it is the same as $({\rm cone}\,\partial f(\bar{x}))^{\circ\circ}$. This is due to $0\notin\partial f(\bar{x})$. Am I right? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Moreover, I do not think a direction polar to all subgradients has to be a descent direction. Consider $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)$ at $(1,0)$. The gradient is $(1,0)$. The direction  $(0,1)$ is polar to $(1,0)$ and belong to the tangent cone. But it is indeed an ascent direction. Please let me know if I miss anything. Thanks.

Comment: For this inequality, I only used the definition of the directional derivative and the convexity of $f$. I did not used that $\mathrm{cone}\partial f(\bar x)$ is closed, but only $\mathrm{cone} A^\circ \supset A^\circ$, see edit.

Comment: Without the assumption that ${\rm cone}\,\partial f(\bar{x})$ is closed, why is the inclusion $N_C(\bar{x})\subset{\rm cone}\,\partial f(\bar{x})$ equivalent to $(N_C(\bar{x}))^{\circ}\supset({\rm cone}\,\partial f(\bar{x}))^{\circ}$?

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right.

Comment: @gerw Based on your last comment, can you please tell me what is the status of the proof you’ve written here? Is it correct as written?

Comment: My proof shows that $N_C(\bar x) \subset \operatorname{cl\,cone}(\partial f(\bar x))$. However, since $\partial f(\bar x)$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and $0 \not\in \partial f(\bar x)$, one can show that $\operatorname{cone}(\partial f(\bar x))$ is already closed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt to explain a proof that I learned from the book Fundamentals of Convex Analysis by Hiriart-Urruty and Lemarechal.

**Some background knowledge and notation:**

I'll first review some relevant background knowledge from convex analysis.

- Let $K \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a convex cone. The "polar" of $K$ is the cone $K^\circ$ defined by
  $$
  K^\circ = \{ w \in \mathbb R^n \mid \langle v, w \rangle \leq 0 \text{ for all } v \in K\}.
  $$
  It can be shown that if $K$ is a closed convex cone, then
  $$
  (K^\circ)^\circ = K.
  $$
- Suppose that $C \subset \mathbb R^n$ is a convex set and $\bar x \in C$. A "feasible vector" or "feasible direction" for $C$ at $\bar x$ is a vector $v \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $\bar x + t v \in C$ for some $t > 0$. (So if you start at the location $\bar x$ and move a short distance in the direction $v$, you will not leave $C$.) The set of all feasible vectors for $C$ at $\bar x$ is denoted $F_C(\bar x)$. The **tangent cone** to $C$ at $\bar x$, denoted $T_C(\bar x)$, is by definition the closure of $F_C(\bar x)$:
  $$
  T_C(\bar x) = \overline{F_C(\bar x)}.
  $$
  (This definition of the tangent cone is only correct when $C$ is convex.)
- The **normal cone** to $C$ at $\bar x$ is the set $N_C(\bar x)$ defined by
  $$
  N_C(\bar x) = \{ w \in \mathbb R^n \mid \langle x - \bar x, w \rangle \leq 0 \text{ for all } x \in C \}.
  $$
  It can be shown that $T_C(\bar x)$ and $N_C(\bar x)$ are both closed convex cones and that
  $$
  N_C(\bar x) = T_C(\bar x)^\circ.
  $$
- Suppose that $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$ is a convex function and $\bar x \in \mathbb R^n$. A "subgradient" of $f$ at $\bar x$ is a vector $g \in \mathbb R^n$ such that
  $$
  f(x) \geq f(\bar x) + \langle g, x - \bar x \rangle \quad \text{for all } x \in \mathbb R^n.
  $$
  The set of all subgradients of $f$ at $\bar x$ is called the "subdifferential" of $f$ at $\bar x$ and is denoted $\partial f(\bar x)$.
- The "effective domain" of a function $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$ is the set $\textbf{dom} \, f$ defined by
  $$
  \textbf{dom} \, f = \{ x \in \mathbb R^n \mid f(x) < \infty \}.
  $$
  It can be shown that if $f$ is convex and $\bar x$ is in the interior of the effective domain of $f$, then $\partial f(\bar x)$ is a non-empty, convex, compact set.
- It can also be shown that if $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R \cup \{\infty \}$ is convex and $\bar x$ is in the interior of the effective domain of $f$, then
  $$
  D_v f(\bar x) = \max_{g \in \partial f(\bar x)} \langle g, v \rangle.
  $$
  Here
  $$
  D_v f(\bar x) = \lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{f(\bar x + tv) - f(\bar x)}{t}
  $$
  is the directional derivative of $f$ at $\bar x$ in the direction $v$.
- If $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$ is convex and $\bar x$ is in the interior of the effective domain of $f$, then the function
  $$
  h(v) = D_v f(\bar x)
  $$
  is a finite sublinear function. It follows that $h$ is continuous.

---

**Statement of theorem:**

Let $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R \cup \{ \infty \}$ be a proper convex function. Suppose that $\bar x$ belongs to the interior of the effective domain of $f$ and that $\inf_{x \in \mathbb R^n} f(x) < f(\bar x)$. If
$$
C = \{ x \in \mathbb R^n \mid f(x) \leq f(\bar x) \}
$$
then
$$
N_C(\bar x) = \mathbb R^+ \partial f(\bar x) = \{ t g \mid t \geq 0, g \in \partial f(\bar x) \}.
$$
Here $N_C(\bar x)$ is the normal cone to $C$ at $\bar x$.

---

**Proof strategy:**

We can prove this theorem in the following steps.

1. We'll first show that the tangent cone to $C$ at $\bar x$ is
   $$
   \tag{$\spadesuit$} T_C(\bar x) = \{ v \in \mathbb R^n \mid D_v f(\bar x) \leq 0\}.
   $$
2. Because $\bar x$ is in the interior of the effective domain of $f$, we have that $\partial f(\bar x)$ is nonempty and compact and
   $$
   D_v f(\bar x) = \max_{g \in \partial f(\bar x)} \langle g, v \rangle \qquad \text{for any } v \in \mathbb R^n.
   $$
   We notice that
   \begin{align}
   \{ v \in \mathbb R^n \mid D_v f(\bar x) \leq 0 \} &= 
   \{ v \in \mathbb R^n \mid \langle g, v \rangle \leq 0 \text{ for all } g \in \partial f(\bar x) \} \\
   &= \{ v \in \mathbb R^n \mid \langle tg, v \rangle \leq 0 \text{ for all } g \in \partial f(\bar x), t \geq 0 \} \\
   \tag{$\clubsuit$}&= \left( \mathbb R^+ \partial f(\bar x) \right)^\circ.
   \end{align}
   Here
   $$
   \mathbb R^+ \partial f(\bar x) = \{ t g \mid g \in \partial g(\bar x) \}
   $$
   is the convex cone generated by $\partial f(\bar x)$.
   Because $\partial f(\bar x)$ is compact, the set $\mathbb R^+ \partial f(\bar x)$ is in fact a *closed* convex cone.
3. Putting the above pieces together, we see that
   \begin{align}
   N_C(\bar x) &= T_C(\bar x)^\circ \\
   &= 
   \{ v \in \mathbb R^n \mid D_v f(\bar x) \leq 0 \}^\circ \\
   &= \left(\mathbb R^+ \partial f(\bar x) \right)^{\circ \circ} \\
   &= \mathbb R^+ \partial f(\bar x).
   \end{align}
   This is what we wanted to show.

---

**Proof details:** Steps 2 and 3 above are already complete. We only need to provide details for step 1.

Equation ($\spadesuit$) seems plausible. Certainly if $v$ is a feasible direction for $C$ at $\bar x$ then $D_vf(\bar x) \leq 0$. Indeed, if $f(\bar x + tv) \leq f(\bar x)$ for all sufficiently small positive $t$, then
$$
D_v f(\bar x) = \lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{f(\bar x + tv) - f(\bar x)}{t} \leq 0.
$$
Because the function $v \mapsto D_v f(\bar x)$ is continuous, it follows that if $v$ is a limit of feasible directions then $D_v f(\bar x) \leq 0$. Thus,
$$
\tag{1} T_C(\bar x) \subset \{ v \in \mathbb R^n \mid D_v f(\bar x) \leq 0\}.
$$
The only challenge is to prove the reverse inclusion.

Let
$$
S = \{ v \in \mathbb R^n \mid D_v f(\bar x) < 0 \}.
$$
It is clear that
$$
S \subset F_C(\bar x)
$$
because if $D_v f(\bar x) < 0$ then moving a short distance away from $\bar x$ in the direction $v$ will reduce the value of $f$.
Thus,
$$
\bar S \subset \overline{F_C(\bar x)} = T_C(\bar x).
$$
But it can be shown that
$$
\tag{2} \bar S = \{ v \in \mathbb R^n \mid D_v f(\bar x) \leq 0 \}.
$$
It follows that
$$
\tag{3} \{ v \in \mathbb R^n \mid D_v f(\bar x) \leq 0 \} \subset T_C(\bar x).
$$
The results (1) and (3) together show that $T_C(\bar x) = \{ v \in \mathbb R^n \mid D_v f(\bar x) \leq 0 \}$, which is what we wanted to show.

---

The only missing detail in the above proof is to establish equation (2).
Let $h:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be the function defined by
$$
h(v) = D_v f(\bar x).
$$
As mentioned in the "background knowledge" section above, this function $h$ is finite and sublinear, hence convex. We are given that there exists a point $x^* \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $f(x^*) < f(\bar x)$. It follows that
$h(v^*) < 0$, where $v^* = x^* - \bar x$. Equation (2) now follows from the following lemma.

**Lemma:** Suppose that $h:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is convex and that $h(v^*) < 0$ for some vector $v^* \in \mathbb R^n$. Then
$$
\tag{4} \overline{\{v \in \mathbb R^n \mid h(v) < 0 \}} = \{ v \in \mathbb R^n \mid h(v) \leq 0 \}.
$$

**Proof of lemma:**
Any convex function $h:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is continuous. Hence, the set $\{ v \in \mathbb R^n \mid h(v) \leq 0 \}$ is closed. It follows that
$$
\tag{5} \overline{\{v \in \mathbb R^n \mid h(v) < 0 \}} \subset \{ v \in \mathbb R^n \mid h(v) \leq 0 \}.
$$

Is the reverse inclusion true also? Well, suppose that $v \in \mathbb R^n$ and $h(v) \leq 0$.
We are given that there exists a vector $v^* \in \mathbb R^n$ such that
$$
h(v^*) < 0.
$$
Let
$$
v_k = \frac{1}{k} v^* + \frac{(k-1)}{k} v \quad \text{for each positive integer }k
$$
and note that $v_k \to v$ as $k \to \infty$.
Because $h$ is convex, we have that
$$
h(v_k) \leq \frac{1}{k} \underbrace{h(v^*)}_{\substack{\big \uparrow\\ < \, 0}} + \frac{(k-1)}{k} \underbrace{h(v)}_{\substack{\big \uparrow \\ \leq \, 0}} < 0
$$
for each positive integer $k$. So $v$ is a limit of vectors $v_k$ which satisfy $h(v_k) < 0$. This shows that
$$
\tag{6} \{ v \in \mathbb R^n \mid h(v) \leq 0 \} \subset \overline{\{v \in \mathbb R^n \mid h(v) < 0 \}}.
$$
Equations (5) and (6) together show that (4) holds, so the lemma is proved.